# Google Checkout API callback URL issue

Tags: .net, google-checkout

I am able to process orders no problem.  However when I look in the integration console I see the following error:

We encountered an error trying to access your server at https://[urlremoved]/registerpayment.aspx -- the error we got is Send failed with code: 401. Response body was:     401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

## Server Error

### 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

#### You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I am using IIS 7 with godaddy hosting account.  I have SSL installed on the server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [one of your recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983408/), I assume that you are submitting the API call through HTTPS from your server-side.

You are receiving this error because your server is not recognizing the authentication credentials of the messages sent back by Google Checkout.

Google prefaces all callbacks and notifications with HTTP basic authentication, using your Merchant ID as the username and your Merchant Key as the password.

An HTTP 401 error indicates that you have not fully completed HTTP basic authentication on your server.

You may find this post useful, which includes example code on how to handle this situation:

- [Google Checkout Developers Forum -  Example code for validating user/passsword in callbacks sent from Google](http://groups.google.com/group/google-checkout-api-dotnet/browse_thread/thread/6e3475a36596f5e7#msg_f42df6c42b423db9)

Comment: Still looks like the authentication problem described here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-checkout-api-dotnet/browse_thread/thread/6e3475a36596f5e7#msg_f42df6c42b423db9. Note point E: You should have one IIS website for the public pages and another one, with Basic Authentication, for the callback pages.

Comment: What I had to do is call go daddy and have them place an advanced ticket for google checkout postbacks. You may get a rep who doesn't know what it is, won't check into and brush you off, but if you call back a couple more times you will get through to someone that will help.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like registerpayment.aspx is requiring authorization. can you browse to it in a new firefox session? maybe it's not setup in iis to accept anonymous

Comment: Yes I can browse to it with no problem.  It just shows a blank page.  It doesn't do anything yet.